# Decoding gZip json with Go

Tags: json, go, gzip

As a Go newbie it's difficult for me to pinpoint the problem area, but hopefully giving you some facts will help.

I'm playing with an API which returns its `Content-Encoding` as gzip. I have written the following to encode my response struct:

```
reader, err = gzip.NewReader(resp.Body)
defer reader.Close()

// print to standard out
//_, err = io.Copy(os.Stdout, reader)
//if err != nil {
//  log.Fatal(err)
//}

// Decode the response into our tescoResponse struct
var response TescoResponse
err := json.NewDecoder(reader).Decode(&response)
```

I've removed the error handling for brevity, but the point of interest is that if I uncomment the print to stdout, I get the expected result. However, the decode doesn't give me what I expect. Any pointers? Is it that the struct has to map exactly to the response??

Here's the full example:
https://play.golang.org/p/4eCuXxXm3T

Comment: The `http` package automatically decodes gzip responses. What you get from `resp.Body` is the uncompressed response. No need to manually decode it. Decode it like this: `json.NewDecoder(resp.Body).Decode(&response)`

Comment: Doing this gives me the error `[NewDecoder]: invalid character '\x1f' looking for beginning of value`

Comment: If the response contains the `Content-Encoding: gzip` header, the `net/http` package will decode it automatically for you. Please check if this is present.

Comment: Have you seen the full example I posted? One of the steps was checking the encoding.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[From the documenation](https://golang.org/src/net/http/transport.go#125):

> DisableCompression, if true, prevents the Transport from requesting
>   compression with an "Accept-Encoding: gzip" request header when the
>   Request contains no existing Accept-Encoding value. If the Transport
>   requests gzip on its own and gets a gzipped response, it's
>   transparently decoded in the Response.Body. However, if the user
>   explicitly requested gzip it is not automatically uncompressed.

Proposed solution:

```
type gzreadCloser struct {
    *gzip.Reader
    io.Closer
}

func (gz gzreadCloser) Close() error {
    return gz.Closer.Close()
}
```

// then in your http call ....

```
    if resp.Header.Get("Content-Encoding") == "gzip" {
        resp.Header.Del("Content-Length")
        zr, err := gzip.NewReader(resp.Body)
        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }
        resp.Body = gzreadCloser{zr, resp.Body}
    }

// then you will be able to decode the json transparently

if err := json.NewDecoder(resp.Body).Decode(&response); err != nil {

}
```

Adapted solution from your code: https://play.golang.org/p/Vt07y_xgak

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. I tried the code that you suggested, but unfortunately I still get an empty struct. If you want to try the api for yourself you could register here; https://devportal.tescolabs.com/

This feels like it really should work.

Comment: See my updated code. I've fixed your TescoResponse using a JSON to Go tool. https://play.golang.org/p/Vt07y_xgak

Comment: Ok, I'm completely bamboozled now. I have run this in both Intellij and Atom, and stepped through the debugger. The struct is empty every time. I'm running the latest go `go version go1.7 darwin/amd64`.

Comment: I have literally copied your code exactly and replaced my api key. The program prints `Data from response &{[]}`

Comment: Thanks @Ezequiel. I completely missed your alteration to the new struct. I'm surprised to see we need to model the complete response as my understanding of the unmarshal was that we could choose the bits we wanted. Either way, poor understanding on my part. Thanks for your support

Answer (score -1):

As @icza mentioned in the comments, decoding isn't required because the gzip reader automatically decodes when you read using it. Perhaps try:

```
ubs := make([]byte, len) // check Content-Length header to set len
n, err := reader.Read(ubs)
err := json.Unmarshal(ubs, &response)
```